# Bigcommerce app coding format for to develop the marketplace app

Tags: php, bigcommerce

I am new to bigcommerce app development.

I need to create app that will add product related information from my app with a custom formatted (image,text anything) details and update in the back-end of the bigcommerce app.

In the front-end, through embedded code, I will display my bigcommerce app details in the product page while ordering the product, product information + my embed code details are also include order details.

Please kindly give a code format link to develop a Bigcommerce App in good manner because i am new to Bigcommerce app development and I am waiting for your response.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Check out some details on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask It would help to see the code you have already tried.

Comment: ok,but no response.simply i need code format to develop best public app Is possible ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get started, you can find a few basic apps on GitHub provided by Bigcommerce. These are templates that will help you kick off the app development. But the architecture of the app and how you structure your logic is purely up to you.

Ruby Example: https://github.com/bigcommerce/hello-world-app-ruby-sinatra

PHP Example: https://github.com/bigcommerce/hello-world-app-php-silex

Comment: Hi i already worked with that php github examples and it's work for me.I am asking "code file folder format to develop a Bigcommerce App".Is anyone know share the link to develop the app.

Comment: @Softsharavana there isn't a set guideline or the best folder structure. In general, if you are using a framework or customer framework you would follow its folder structure and keep the integrations in a service layer

Comment: ok,i am using codeigniter as a framework how to integrated in the service layers and create a embed code for frontend display.

Comment: @Softsharavana if you do a search you can find a few projects on GitHub to get an idea. https://github.com/search?p=2&q=bigcommerce+app&type=Repositories